# How to trigger Javascript in CRM VIew Refreshing?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I create one javascript function For calculate the No.Of Days from created Date and show in one Field.

And I add that script in Form Load and as well Form Save Actions.It was Working Fine.

Now My question is,I need to trigger that javascript function grid's(view) refresh.Or I need to calculate and show the No Of Days Field without opening Form.

Now the noofdays field affected when the form will getting open.

I need noofdays field automatically updated From the Created on date?How to do this...Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this, noofdays field not saved, when the form is saved? can't you use this field directly in view? why do you want to again calculate in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger an javaScript function without opening the from is not possible.

If i understood correctly, you want to display the time period between the creation and current date in days.
If so:

**A Solution would be:**
On creation of the record the noofdays field will always be 1 or 0. However you look at it.
So you can fill that field on creation per default to 1 per Plugin, JS, or simply per workflow.

Now you need to update this field each day via workflow.
The workflow must retrieve all records, calcualte and update the noofdays field.
I reccomend to run this workflow after midnight.

**The other solution: (I do not reccomend)**
Create an Plugin which is registerd to the message "retrieve" and "retrieve multiple".
If the message is triggered, check if you are in the right entity and fake the output of the noofdays field or update it.